# How do I get the SCIM group name from the SCIM group ID?

Tags: linux, azure, nfs4

I don't know anything about Azure SCIM. My customer sets up the SCIM groups. nfs4_getfacl can tell me the numerical IDs of files and directories but I don't know how to match those with group names. getent groups can't find the numerical IDs.

Again, I can retrieve the numeric ID from the group name but I cannot do the inverse.

Thanks.

Comment: nfs4 client expect LDAP to map uids to string principals. So, you need to export SCIM information with LDAP